# Linux kernel 2.6.38 compilation error

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

When I try to compile the Linux 2.6.38 kernel on my Linux PC, I get:

```
$ make defconfig
$ make
```

I get:

```
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1966:2: error: unknown field ‘num_private’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1966:2: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967:2: error: unknown field ‘num_private_args’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967:2: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘ndis_handler_def’)
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970:2: error: unknown field ‘private’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970:2: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970:2: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970:2: error: (near initialization for ‘ndis_handler_def.num_standard’)
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1971:2: error: unknown field ‘private_args’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1971:26: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
make[2]: *** [ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ubuntu/ndiswrapper] Error 2
make: *** [ubuntu] Error 2
```

Any ideas how to solve this and why it happen with default configuration?

Comment: Can you detail the steps on how you got kernel 2.6.38 source on your system?  The errors above seem to be related to `ndiswrapper` which I did not think was part of the official kernel.  It could be possible that the version of ndiswrapper that's intertwined with the kernel source is not compatible with 2.6.38.  Probably what you need to do is download a fresh copy of the source, complile and make sure the kernel is running OK, and then compile ndiswrapper from source.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63068/linux-kernel-compilation-error#question)

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same error when I pulled kernel source on an Oneiric host
and tried to build it today.

You can look through the source file to pinpoint the root cause, but to
cut to the chase, the config variable `WEXT_PRIV` is not set, so an include
file that has those definitions is not included.

The Ubuntu kernel patch that adds this code is not perfect.  My workaround
was to find a wireless device in the list that would cause this config item
to get selected.  I didn't care what the device was since I wasn't going to
use the driver, but it got `CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV` to be set in the `.config` file.

Quite at random from the available choices, I used Cisco/Aironet device.
I haven't tested the kernel yet, but it does build correctly.